# Rails Form helpers - Input - Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a this form.

```
 <%= form_for @snitch, html: { class: "form-actions", method: 'delete' } do |form| %>
 <span class="button-text"><%= link_to 'NO WAY!', home_base_url_or_default(root_path), rel: "modal:close" %></span>
 <input type="submit" class="button button--modal delete-snitch" data-snitch-id="<% @snitch.token %>" value="Yes, delete it.">
 <% end %>
```

As you can see on the 3rd line there is an input type. I have this attribute on it `data-snitch-id` I have it set to the snitch token. I'm just wondering if that is correct because its coming back as undefined...

Here is how I know.

I'm using it for a Ajax call

```
    $(document).on('click','.delete-snitch', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var snitchID = $(this).attr('data-snitch-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/snitches/' + snitchID,
        datatype: 'json'
        success: function(){
            $('#tr-for-snitch-' + snitchID).fadeOut
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working because the `data-snitch-id` comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<%= @snitch.token %>` instead of `<% @snitch.token %>` to output that value.